# Choose sorting type in flash.net.FileReferenceList browse method

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, filereferencelist

It is possible in the open file dialog of

```
flash.net.FileReferenceList
```

to specify the file sorting order, ie the equivalent to make in Windows File Explorer "Arrange icons by"?

Answer (score 1):

The short answer: No.
The FileReference.browse (to select a single file) and the fileReferenceList.browse (to select multiple files). There is no hook to the underlying file system to sort the dialog entries.

Comment: Perhaps, but it assumes all the OS's has a similar feature, if not that flash would need to sort it.